# Sheets query matches with new line

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

How do you get a sheets query to match within cells that contain new line characters?

I tried `matches '.*Something.*`and `(?s).*Something.*` but I can't get it to work.

I would rather not change the data that is fed into the query.

Here is a sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sYqhuW-5ldfz69LZjSI_L6FwdfGs6pXeMakJKrtMsCw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's got to be a way to make this happen. But I haven't been able to make it possible through sheet functions. Would you be down for a custom functions in Apps Script? Have you used Apps Script before?

Comment: I have used app scripts before, I am looking for a solution to be able to use the built in "Query" function though.

Comment: So what is the reason why @player0 answer does not work for you? Does creating an additional helper column be feasible for you?

Comment: @player0's answer wasn't using "match" which enables you to use other regex patterns.
I wrote in the question that a helper column wouldn't either be ultimate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have come up with:

```
=QUERY(A2:A7, "where lower(A) matches '(.*\n)*.*(pear).*(\n.*)*'")
```

The `lower` is completely optional I just used to help me with the testing. Just remember to adapt your `regEx` accordingly.

Hope this works for you because I took an embarrassing amount of time to do this.

[image: Example inside Sheet]

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
=QUERY(A2:A7, "where lower(A) contains 'pear'")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my question, but I tried your answer and it still only matches the last cell in the sample sheet. I want it to return all the cells which contain pear (all except for one). The issue is not the fact that it is upper case or lower case.

Comment: "Contains" would work in the spesific case I am working on now, but regex lets you do much more. Would you know how to do it with "matches"?. Also why do you use lower(A)?